# DateTime vs DateTime2 Time Range Discrepancy

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, types

Looking over the differences between `DateTime` and `DateTime2`, I noticed that the deprecated `DateTime` datatype has an odd time range of `00:00:00.000` through `23:59:59.997`, whereas `DateTime2` data type has a limit of `00:00:00.0000000` through `23:59:59.9999999`.

I speculated that this limitation likely has something to do with earlier limitations, could someone please explain why this limitation is in place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The weird limit and behavior (such as the last digit always being 0, 3 or 7) is because of how the time portion is internally stored in `DATETIME`:

The time portion is stored as the number of *ticks* since 00:00:00 ([1](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-get-sql-server-dates-and-times-horribly-wrong/) and [2](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/datadesign/how-are-dates-stored-in-sql-server/)). Each tick is exactly 1/300<sup>th</sup> of a second. Keeping this in mind, the `DATETIME` type is only capable of storing values such as:

```
00:00:00.000 -- 0 ticks
00:00:00.003 -- 1 tick,      1/300 = 0.003333 sec
00:00:00.007 -- 2 ticks,     2/300 = 0.006666 sec
00:00:00.010 -- 3 ticks,     3/300 = 0.01 sec
00:00:00.997 -- 299 ticks, 299/300 = 0.996666 sec
00:00:01.000 -- 300 ticks, 300/300 = 1 second
```

Since it is not possible to store half or quarter ticks, `DATETIME` cannot store or represent the values in between. For example, if you try to store a value such as `CAST('2000-01-01 00:00:00.999' AS DATETIME)` it will be rounded to `2000-01-01 00:00:01.000`.

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with the precision. You can make your `DateTime2` definition have a similar precision to `DateTime` if you define it as `DateTime2(3)`. A precision of `7` happens to be the default for `DateTime2` which is what you are seeing in your question.

---

See also [datetime2 (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) documentation

> precision - 0 to 7 digits, with an accuracy of 100ns. The default precision is 7 digits.

---

See also [datetime (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> Use the time, date, datetime2 and datetimeoffset data types for new work. These types align with the SQL Standard. They are more portable. time, datetime2 and datetimeoffset provide more seconds precision. datetimeoffset provides time zone support for globally deployed applications

Answer (score 1):

First thing first... DATETIME is not deprecated.

The reason for the discrepancy is that the original date time has a resolution of 3 milliseconds. The newer DATETIME2 has a resolution of 100 nanoseconds.

The "3 milliseconds" resolution of DATETIME is why you see 23:59:59.997 rather than 23:59:59.999 before rolling over to 00:00:00.000

Comment: Sorry, I was going off of the note microsoft left here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

They suggest using DateTime2 over DateTime, so I assumed it was depreciated.

Comment: No worries. I agree, the wording is a bit misleading. The reality is that it would be damned near impossible to to deprecate the DATETIME data type. Aside from the difference in resolution, there is also a difference in the underling storage structure that allows direct math on DATETIME that simply won't work WITH DATETIME2.