# Declare date and selected date not match

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, stored-procedures

I have declared a datetime variable called @dt -

```
declare @dt Datetime = '2019-01-29 11:06:31.095'
```

When i select the variable it gives wrong date

```
select @dt --it gives '2019-01-29 11:06:31.097'
```

Comment: Have a look into https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108287/why-does-my-query-search-datetime-not-match

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52431279/datetime-vs-datetime2-time-range-discrepancy

Answer (score 6):

According to the [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#rounding-of-datetime-fractional-second-precision):

> datetime values are rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds, as shown in the following table.

The table in the link provided clearly demonstrates the reason your value is converted from `'.095'` to `'.097'`:

```
User-specified value    System stored value
-----------------------------------------------
01/01/98 23:59:59.999   1998-01-02 00:00:00.000
01/01/98 23:59:59.995

01/01/98 23:59:59.996

01/01/98 23:59:59.997

01/01/98 23:59:59.998   1998-01-01 23:59:59.997
```

Comment: Is there any solution that gives both date same?

Comment: The soltion is to migrate your code to use `datetime2(3)`

Comment: @SalmanA it is working when i use select statement but when i insert that variable in my table then it inserted as '2019-01-29 11:06:31.097' because the datatypes of column is datetime.i have to overcome from this problem.

Comment: @Thebeginner There is no way to store a `'.095'` value in a `datetime` column. You have to convert the data type to `datetime2` as @Salman indicated.

Answer (score 4):

What is not mentioned in the manual is the fact that [`DATETIME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) stores dates with a resolution of 1/300<sup>th</sup> of a second i.e. multiples of 0.0033333333... second. Here are some literals and resulting datetime values:

```
literal                    datetime
2019-01-29 11:06:31.094    2019-01-29 11:06:31.093
2019-01-29 11:06:31.095    2019-01-29 11:06:31.097
2019-01-29 11:06:31.096    2019-01-29 11:06:31.097
2019-01-29 11:06:31.097    2019-01-29 11:06:31.097
2019-01-29 11:06:31.098    2019-01-29 11:06:31.097
2019-01-29 11:06:31.099    2019-01-29 11:06:31.100
```

You should start using [`DATETIME2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) datatype which has wider range (year 0001 to 9999) and more precision (up to 7 digits after decimal). You can declare the column as `DATETIME2(3)` to have exactly three digits after decimal.

Comment: it is working when i insert that date in my table which has datetime datatype?

Comment: you simply cannot store values such as .001, .002, .995 etc inside `datetime` as-is, they will be rounded (working = rounded then stored).

Answer (score 2):

datetime in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> Accuracy - Rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds
>
> Use the time, date, datetime2 and datetimeoffset data types for new
>   work. These types align with the SQL Standard. They are more portable.
>   time, datetime2 and datetimeoffset provide more seconds precision.
>   datetimeoffset provides time zone support for globally deployed
>   applications.